# Pandas Dataframes: How to include data inside hourly intervals using datetime arrays

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am trying to include only data inside my dataframe which is in specific time intervals. Following code snippet should clarify my problem,

```
  index = df2.index.unique()
  for i in range(len(index) - 1):
        valid_time_frame = (df.index > index[i].date() +
                           _datetimeOffset(starting_hours)) & \
                           (df.index <= index[i + 1].date() +
                           _datetimeOffset(ending_hours))
        df.loc[timer, ['index']] = index[i + 1]

  def _datetimeOffset(hours):
        return pd.offsets.DateOffset(hours=hours, minutes=00)
```

df and df2 being two pandas dataframes. This for-loop takes too long when your dataframe gets very big. I tried to vectorize it but I couldn't manage. Has anybody experienced this issue?

Best regards! :-)

Comment: Look at [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html#pandas-dataframe-resample).

Comment: The problem with resample and df.between_time is that index = df2.index. If  index=df.index, then this would be the solution.

Comment: can you create some dummy data and expected output?